# WCF: The sequence has been terminated by the remote endpoint.

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am getting this error, "The sequence has been terminated by the remote endpoint. The inactivity timeout of (00:10:00) has been exceeded. The reliable session was faulted."

Comment: You need to give more details, and however obvious it may seem, what is your question?

Comment: I have tried by exceeding its inactivity timeout, but still getting the same error. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be generated if service takes too much time to execute at least more than 10 minutes.
if you think reliable session is necessary for your application, you can increase the inactivity time under reliable session section under binding configuration section.

other wise you should turn off that section by marking Enabled property to false under ReliableSession properties under binding configuration section. but you should check why your service takes so much time.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Also I like to mention, you need to determine how much time the service needs to execute  the  operation. you need to set atleast or more than that duration on inactivity time out property.